# How to Merge a git branch in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, git

Eclipse integration with Git is incredibly confusing; this question focuses on one area of trouble -- merging.

We have the master branch.  In order to do experimental work, I created a test branch, changed the code.  When it was done, I want to merge it back.

The Git repositories view shows:

quiz2 [master]

> Branches
>   Local
>   master
>          testing

Right clicking on master, I select merge and select to merge with testing.

There are three options:

Commit
No Commit
Squash

I have actually tried all three of these.  Each ends with the same result, claiming that master is up to date.  But that is nonsense, the two branches are different.

I want to apply the changes I made in branch test to master.

I note there are other questions with Eclipse and git such as: [How to merge code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890514/how-to-merge-code-in-eclipse)

but the answers describe things I am not seeing, like a "Git Staging view"

THe only view I can see is "git repository" and "package explorer"

Comment: The link does not help.  The problem is, I can see that Master has a number of classes with errors in them.  I fixed those classes in the test branch.  I click on the master branch, say merge with test, and it says that master is up to date.  But I can see the two are different. What can it possibly mean?

Comment: did you commit the changes onto the test branch?